# mySQL - SELECT date range overlap in single table

Tags: mysql

Sorry about possibly botching this question earlier...it still eludes me.

Basically, I have a single table that tracks a group of "approvers" for reports. also tracks when reports are "created" and when they were "submitted."

I am looking to flag when there are date/time overlaps for any reports.

Example (one table, "reports"):

```
"Created"                 "Submitted"                "ApproverID"
4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:30:32 AM          10
4/20/2012 5:08:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:45:32 AM          10
4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM          4/19/2012 5:38:16 PM          15
```

...my need is to return the following (where the same approver overlaps date/time)

```
 "Created"                 "Submitted"                "ApproverID"    
4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:30:32 AM          10            
4/20/2012 5:08:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:45:32 AM          10
```

so the approver (10 in this example) had a window that overlapped these reports.  seems like a SELECT with a BETWEEN clause...but I am a bit stumped.

I had something simple like the following:

```
SELECT Created, LastModified, ApprovalGroupID, count(*) 
FROM   shifthandover.uniquereports
WHERE ApprovalGroupID between Created and LastModified
```

Help Appreciated!

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's definitely more complicated than a SELECT BETWEEN...

Answer (score 3):

From your question, I understand that an 'overlap' occurs when a second (or subsequent) report is created after a first (or earlier) report is created, but before that prior report is submitted - i.e. the approver was working on multiple reports at once. Is that correct?

You might try joining the reports table onto itself - e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM reports r1 
JOIN reports r2 
ON r1.approvalId=r2.approvalId 
AND r2.created>r1.created 
AND r2.created<r1.submitted
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   Created, LastModified, ApprovalGroupID, count(*) --whatever those are
FROM     uniquereports AS r1
JOIN     uniquereports AS r2.ApproverID = r1.ApproverID AND r2 ON r2.id = r1.id -- the unique id of the table, or use whatever combination to get a unique representation, which is important.
WHERE    r2.Created >= r1.Created AND r2.Created <= r1.LastModified OR
         r2.LastModified >= r1.Created AND r2.LastModified <= r1.LastModified OR
         r2.Created <= r1.Created AND r2.LastModified >= r1.LastModified OR
         r2.Created >= r1.Created AND r2.LastModified <= r1.LastModified             
GROUP BY r1.ApproverID
```

The last `OR` clause is not useful here since we have already considered the case of `r2.Created` being greater than `r1.Created` in first `OR` clause, considering technically a record can not be modified before its created. Still added there to ensure all cases.

Answer (score 1):

This provides the approver_id and the number of overlaps for that approver.

```
select approver_id, count(*)/2 from (
  select t1.approver_id 
  from reports t1 
  join reports t2 on 
     t2.approver_id = t1.approver_id 
     AND t1.id <> t2.id 
  where
     NOT((t1.submitted < t2.created) 
     OR (t1.created > t2.submitted))
  ) t2 group by approver_id;
```

The count(*)/2 is there so you don't double count the permutation where A overlaps B and B overlaps A. Also, I assume that you have a record_id or other primary key to prevent the record from counting itself.